# Angular2 child property change not firing update on bound property

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a simple custom directive with an input, that I'm binding to in my component. But for whatever reason, the ngOnchanges() method doesn't fire when changing a child property of the input property.

my.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyDirective} from './my.directive';

@Component({
    directives: [MyDirective],
    selector: 'my-component', 
    templateUrl: 'Template.html'
})

export class MyComponent {
    test: { one: string; } = { one: "1" }

    constructor( ) {
        this.test.one = "2";
    }
    clicked() {
        console.log("clicked");
        var test2: { one: string; } = { one :"3" };
        this.test = test2; // THIS WORKS - because I'm changing the entire object
        this.test.one = "4"; //THIS DOES NOT WORK - ngOnChanges is NOT fired=
    }
}
```

my.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {OnChanges} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[my-directive]',
    inputs: ['test']
})

export class MyDirective implements OnChanges {
    test: { one: string; } = { one: "" }

    constructor() { }

    ngOnChanges(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

template.html

```
<div (click)="clicked()"> Click to change </div>
<div my-directive [(test)]="test">
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact, it's a normal behavior and Angular2 doesn't support deep comparison. It's only based on reference comparison. See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6458.

That said they are some workarounds to notify the directive that some fields in an object were updated.

- **Referencing the directive from the component**

  ```
  export class AppComponent {
    test: { one: string; } = { one: '1' }
    @ViewChild(MyDirective) viewChild:MyDirective;

    clicked() {
      this.test.one = '4';
      this.viewChild.testChanged(this.test);
    }
  }
  ```

  In this case, the testChanged method of the directive is called explicitly. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TvibzkWUKNxH6uGkL6mJ?p=preview.
- **Using an event within a service**

  A dedicated service defines `testChanged` event

  ```
  export class ChangeService {
    testChanged: EventEmitter;

    constructor() {
      this.testChanged = new EventEmitter();
    }
  }
  ```

  The component uses a service to trigger the `testChanged` event:

  ```
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor(service:ChangeService) {
      this.service = service;
    }

    clicked() {
      this.test.one = '4';
      this.service.testChanged.emit(this.test);
    }
  }
  ```

  The directive subscribes to this `testChanged` event in order to be notified

  ```
  export class MyDirective implements OnChanges,OnInit {
    @Input()
    test: { one: string; } = { one: "" }

    constructor(service:ChangeService) {
      service.testChanged.subscribe(data => {
        console.log('test object updated!');
      });
    }
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Neither of these seem to work for me. I tried explicitly setting the testChange emitter to @Ouput() and tried being type-specifc with the <T> value, but it just doesn't fire the ngOnchanges in the directive.

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use because I made it work with the beta0 one?

Comment: I'm also on beta.0. Your testChange declaration is invalid for me as well (have to either assign <T> or forego the type declaration and go straight to: testChange = new EventEmitter();)
Am I supposed to subscribe in some special way in my directive for it to register the eventEmitter?

Comment: No, the event is detected by Angular itself and it triggers the `onChanges` method...

Comment: I hust saw in your code that you don't use an `@Input` for your `test` field within the `MyDirective` component...

Comment: That's because I declared the inputs in the inputs array in the @Component decorator (I have also tried it with the @Input())

Comment: Doh - of course your code works, I wasn't paying attention. In your code you specifically set this.test to a NEW object - just like the code I have that works. When you ONLY change the child property, it doesn't work

Comment: Oh my god! You're right... I investigated a bit more and get some feedbacks from angular github. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see... Well, that's disappointing. Honestly, I think it should be possible to decide whether or not you need deep-comparison. The performance can't be that bad, if pretty much every other js framework supports it.