# ngModel updates in controller, but not in the view, angular 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular

I have an input in my view:

```
  <label for="map-latitude_input">Latitude {{mapLatitudeInput}}</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="00.000"
    [(ngModel)]="mapLatitudeInput"
    [ngFormControl]="newListingForm.find('mapLatitudeInput')"
    id="map-latitude_input"
    class="transparent">
```

and inside my controller I am listening to map drag event from google maps api. On drag I want to update value inside my input and in its associated label. At the moment this looks like this:

```
//Update coordinates on map drag
map.addListener('drag', (event) => {
  this.mapLatitudeInput = map.getCenter().lat();
  console.log(this.mapLatitudeInput);
});
```

Now when I drag a map console keeps outputting correct value as I move it around, however in my view it stays exactly the same. What I also noticed is that if I drag map around and than do some action like select an option in select menu within same form that my input is in, it updates `mapLatitudeInput` to correct value, i'm not sure why this happens, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I assume `map.getCenter().lat();` returns the same object every time only with updated values. You could verify that by comparing the returned value with the previous one.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What confuses me is that printing this.mapLatitudeInput in console actually shows me that it is updating as I expect, however it does not reflect in the view input, value there stays the same unless I do other actions in the form, i.e start typing in another input or something. Do you reckon this could be a bug within angular 2?

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information. It could as well be a zone issue like @thierrytemplier explained in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps due to ZoneJS. This question could give you some hints: [View is not updated on change in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2).

From where do you get your map instance. If it's instantiated outside a zone, Angular2 won't be able to detect updates of the `mapLatitudeInput` attribute.

You could try something like that:

```
export class MapComponent {
  constructor(ngZone:NgZone) {
    this.ngZone = ngZone;
  }

  map.addListener('drag', (event) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() =>
      this.mapLatitudeInput = map.getCenter().lat();
      console.log(this.mapLatitudeInput);
    });
  });
```

This question could be also related to your problem: [Angular2 child property change not firing update on bound property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761224/angular2-child-property-change-not-firing-update-on-bound-property/).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It's part of `angular2/core`. See this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html. Just import it and use it as constructor parameter...

Comment: You are outstanding help, thank you so much for your answers, it is really helping me out in learning angular 2.

Comment: In addition you could read the Mark Rajcok's awesome answer on ZoneJS / Angular2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569094/what-is-the-angular2-equivalent-to-an-angularjs-watch ;-)

Comment: I will be reading a lot about angular 2 this weekend, thats for sure. Just jumped on it to make a test project to see if I like it, hence tons of questions haha, but so far it's been amazing.