# Trouble with *ngIf in Angular 2 (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 beta (TypeScript). I met a weird problem. I tried Chrome, Firefox, Opera, all same results.

When I click the "Toggle" button, it can successfully show/hide the text "Hello World!".

When I send the command from another browser using socket, the boolean "show" changes successfully background, however, the text does not show/hide, which looks like the page does not refresh.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/bootstrap';
import {NgIf} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
    directives: [NgIf],
    template: `
      <button (click)="clicked()">Toggle</button>
      <div>
        <div *ngIf="show">
          <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    `
})
class App {
    show: boolean = true;

    constructor() {
        Socket.on {
            If (getMessage) {
                this.show = !this.show;
            }
        }
    }

    clicked() {
        this.show = !this.show;
    }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that it's a problem related to Zone. The latter is responsible to notify Angular that it needs to handle an update.

This question could give you some hints: [View is not updated on change in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2).

You could try something like that:

```
export class App {
  constructor(ngZone:NgZone) {
    this.ngZone = ngZone;
    Socket.on {
      this.ngZone.run(() =>
        If (getMessage) {
            this.show = !this.show;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  }
```

This question could be also related to your problem: [Angular2 child property change not firing update on bound property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761224/angular2-child-property-change-not-firing-update-on-bound-property/).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 8):

Seems the `Socket` code runs outside Angulars zone. Inject `NgZone` and use `zone.run(...)` so Angular to make Angular aware of necessary change detection.

```
class App {
  show: boolean = true;

  constructor(zone: NgZone) {
    Socket.on {
        if (getMessage) {
            zone.run(() => { this.show = !this.show; });
        }
    }
  }


  clicked() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response! It works! Both yours and thierry's are correct. Hope you can understand I can only pick one answer.

Comment: @HongboMiao that's just fine, no worries :)

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer every time i check the author for an awesome answer i found you , Thanks hidden Ninja :)