# How to update view in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have this input

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name=$event">
```

And `this.name = 'Adam';`

When I get a new name from the back end and set the value with `this.name = res.data`, input value on page doesn't change. Why?

Comment: Try with shorter version: [(ngModel)]="name"

Comment: If the call to the server is done by code running outside Angular you need to use `constructor(private zone: NgZone){} ...zone.run(...)`. Your question doesn't provide enough information. Please explain how the value is changed.

Comment: You need to give us more details on the way you get data from server. The problem is surely related to zone as Günter stated ;-)

Comment: This question with responses from Günter and I could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875066/trouble-with-ngif-in-angular-2-typescript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

If it is not working check your `Class` definition.