# Angular structural directive input change not detected after update from ngOnChanges

Tags: angular8, angular-directive

So, I have the following structure:

parent component > child component > structural loading directive

The child component has a boolean flag that instructs the directive to show or not loading animation. The child component has internal event handlers that update the flag, do some work and then reset it. All working fine when done this way.
The child component also listens for input changes from the parent component.
And when that happens, within ngOnChanges, the flag is toggled again but this time, loading is not working. The directive is not aware of the changes at all and does not change the HTML.

I tried to update the flag directly from the parent component but to no avail.
I also came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761224/angular2-child-property-change-not-firing-update-on-bound-property) but couldn't resolve the issue.
Any input on this would be more than appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide code along with this?

Comment: Excuse me for the bad description, I cannot share the actual code. Started preparing a demo snippet but then found a solution - shared in a separate answer.